# Icecast header response is both 400 and 200

Tags: networking, icecast, internet-radio

I have Icecast 2.4.4 running on a Windows box at sub.domain.org.  My website is on a different server at domain.org.

When I SSH into my Linux host shell and run curl to the mount point I get a response of 400, but if I do wget I get a response of 200.  How can this be?

```
# wget https://sub.domain.org/live.mp3
--2018-12-19 17:52:58--  https://sub.domain.org/live.mp3 Resolving sub.domain.org... 111.111.111.111 Connecting to
sub.domain.org|111.111.111.111|:443... connected. HTTP request sent,
awaiting **response... 200 OK** Length: unspecified [audio/mpeg] Saving
to: `live.mp3'

    [                        <=>                 ] 96,600      3.93K/s              ^C

# curl --head  https://sub.domain.org/live.mp3
HTTP/1.0 **400 Bad Request**
Server: Icecast 2.4.4
Connection: Close Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2018
00:53:32 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control:
no-cache, no-store Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT Pragma:
no-cache Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in case of cURL you are passing the `--head` parameter. This tells cURL to make a `HTTP HEAD` request instead of the `HTTP GET` request that `wget` performs.

Icecast does **not** support `HTTP HEAD` requests and thus the `HTTP 400` response is fully justified.

Comment: Thanks, TBR.  I didn't know that about Icecast.