# How can I check if a webm icecast stream is active?

Tags: javascript, axios, webm, icecast, internet-radio

I'm trying to check if a webm Icecast stream is on. For HLS streams I use axios.head method like this:

```
try {
    let res = await axios.head(url);
    return /2\d\d/.test('' + res.status);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err', url, err);
    return false;
}
```

And it works fine. But in the process of debugging I learned that [Icecast doesn't support HEAD method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861678/icecast-header-response-is-both-400-and-200).

OPTIONS method also fails for Icecast streams ( I get net::ERR_FAILED). I can't do a get to a stream as it would get the whole stream. I just want to make sure that it's active.

How can I check that a webm stream from Icecast exists ?

**EDIT**

Let me explain a bit futher. This is a generic stream site. The user informs several live streams that he/she wants to see and their time. These streams can be anywhere in the web. At the start time, the user goes to a player page and plays the stream **if it's active**.

The "if it's active" part is what I'm trying to to here.

Comment: icecast has endpoints that return XML (or JSON in later versions) that give you such information - just [read the documentation](https://icecast.org/docs/)

Comment: Yes... but I don't have access to the server... I'm doing a streaming feature in my project. So the user just enters in an admin screen something like http://example.com/streams/whatever,webm and I want to be able to play that stream, but first I want to check if it's active.

Comment: if you have no access to the server, how do you expect to test if the stream (which is sent by the server you say you have no access to) is up?

Comment: What I meant is that I don't have access to the stream server for configuration. My project accepts streams from anywhere. It's generic. Not a specific server. I just need to know by the stream url if it's active or not. The above code works perfectly for HLS streams.

Comment: Oh, I see - you have a stream URL only - I guess you could use XMLHttpRequest, and abort the request once `.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED` - since at that point you will determine if the stream is up (I think) - or maybe when `.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.LOADING` - you'll have partial data in `.resposnseText`

Comment: Good point. Will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icecast doesn't support CORS properly, so at the moment there isn't a good way to do this via Fetch or XHR.

However, it seems to me that all you need to do is attempt to play the stream.  Then, see if an error occurs.

```
const audio = new Audio('https://example.com/stream');
audio.addEventListener('error', () => {
  // Stream didn't load, so in all probability it's not online!
});

audio.play(); // This needs to happen on a trusted event, like a click handler, due to autoplay policy
```